# Excel parsing C# without interop

Tags: c#, excel, parsing

What is best way and practics parsing excel files without using COM interop or OLEDB connection

Comment: You are in essence asking if there are any 3rd party libraries that will open Excel documents. That kind of question is unfortunately off-topic here on SO.

Comment: Lasse already answered you: look for third party libraries. I don't know in C#, but you can have a look at http://www.python-excel.org/ for Python, just to have an idea.

Comment: Try searching here to see if anything looks helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444522/import-and-export-excel-what-is-the-best-library or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2010/05/27/parsing-and-reading-large-excel-files-with-the-open-xml-sdk.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624333/how-do-i-read-data-from-a-spreadsheet-using-the-openxml-format-sdk

Comment: Thank's to all for answers

Answer (score 0):

You could use [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/), im currently using it in my project. Its pretty cool,

[Code Sample for Excel](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Excel_Examples_EN)

**Features**

Office integration without version limitations

All features of the Office versions 2000, 2002, 2003, 2007, 2010, 2013 are included

Active support in version independent development (please scroll down)

Syntactically and semantically identical to the Microsoft Interop Assemblies

No training if you already know the Office object model, use your existing PIA code

Reduced and more readable code with automatic management of COM proxies

Usable with .NET version 2.0 or higher

Easy Addin Development

No deployment hurdles, no registration

No dependencies, no interop assemblies, no need for VSTO

Visual Studio Project Templates and Wizards available Photo Gallery

Answer (score 0):

I have had good success with [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/).